# How can i get notifications about geo position changes in tabris?

Tags: geolocation

I am experimenting with tabris and am looking into the geo api at the moment.

I am able to get my current position from the Geolocation class via getCurrentPosition(). My problem is that i don't want to perform pull requests all the time to get geo updates.

Instead i would like to get notified of position changes whenever the user moves his device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get notified about your location change, just use the method Geolocation.watchPosition() to add a Listener. This can then be used e.g. to update the UI.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what i have been looking for.